# Potbelly pig's front legs pull to chest and she screams in pain

Tags: health, pig, pain

Maggie is an 8 year old, 150 lbs (68 kg) potbelly pig. She is often unable to walk. She goes to move forward, but then her front legs go tight against her chest and she sits up, screaming. She looks just like a begging dog, sitting up on her haunches with her front legs tight against her chest, dangling down.  This happens daily. We have relocated her from her pen to a double kennel in the barn so we can monitor her more carefully. I tried to pull a front leg away from her chest today, and I was unable to budge it. This is not voluntary. Has anyone seen this?

She has been seen by 4 different vets. She is on Meloxicam, which is an anti-inflammatory. I see no changes in this odd positioning and behavior. That is why I am reaching out here. We are a farm rescue, by the way. Lots of pigs, little and massive. Haven't seen this before, and we love Maggie. She used to go to schools to teach kids about proper animal treatment. "Sitting pretty" was one of her tricks. This is what it looks like, but again, definately NOT voluntary.

Comment: Welcome to Pet Exchange, if your pet is in pain you need to take her to the vet! There is nothing we on the internet can do to help!

Comment: I'm not sure this helps, but could you descrive her posture during those episodes? Are her legs stiff and straight or bend at the joints and drawn in? Are only her front legs affected? How often does she have these episodes? Does it only happen in certain situations like when she's standing up or after she's been walking a lot? Please [edit] yur question to add as much information as you can.

Comment: How often happens it? I do not wish your pig it will happen again, but maybe it is possible to make a photo? Or some kind of drawing? I can not imagine the position only from your description clearly :( I found a lot of descriptions about issues woth the hind-legs, but nothing to the front legs...

Comment: I can't get a photo to upload! I tried and tried. Maggie sits up on her butt, like a dog, and her front legs look like they are just dangling down, but they are actually very rigid. She is not active at this point. She moves a bit, but I think about half the time she ends up in this position, then kind of flops forward so she's laying down on her belly. With her head on a pillow!

Comment: Im sorry but im voting to close this question due to it not having enough evidence/not belonging on this site. Best of luck to your pig and always feel free to ask again when you have a photo/video of the situation.

Comment: Well, it definately belongs on this site, and if anyone else had a pig that did this, thry would know exactly what I was talking about: a pig does not normally sit on their butt, looking like a dog, begging for food. However, there are no answers here either for our poor Maggie, so please, close the dang question Joseph.

Comment: Just wondering if you got an answer on this? My pot belly pig just started doing this…he has a hard time getting up and when he does he front legs go straight and stuff to his belly and he nose dives forward?